# VB.NET Forms GridView on ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Is there a way to use a VB.NET Forms DataGridView object on an ASPX page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, the WinForms control is named `DataGridView`.

But to answer the question, no, they are built on two fundamentally different technologies.